# Custom UI Element CSS Padding Issues

Tags: user-interface, css, drop-down-menu, select-menu

I have created a custom drop-down element, which is listed on this page:

> http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/2snUH/3/

Click on the drop-down menu in the "Result" secion, and you will see the problem. By rolling over the choices in the expanded drop-down list, you notice the roll-over indicators don't stretch to the available width.

While *still maintaining the width of the menu when it was collapsed*, how can I stretch the background color of each menu item? I'd also like each of the menu items to remain on their own line. A couple of adjustments that I made the CSS caused some of the list items to wrap their own text.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative margins with `width: auto` instead of `width: 100%` for items:

```
UL.dropdown.open LI {
    margin: 0 -23px 0 -10px;
    padding-right: 23px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/2snUH/4/ .

Or get rid of horizontal padding for `UL` (and specify horizontal padding for `LI` instead), and then you will not need negative margins for `LI` items.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the width of the li elements use:

```
    ul.dropdown.open {
    padding: 5px 0;
}
    ul.dropdown.open li {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
        text-wrap: none;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```